# How to show marker on that lat/long when appending lat/long in Here We Go Url and How can i get Phone number from place api

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest, here-autocomplete

I used Reverse Geocoding in my code using TRACK_POSITION where i need to pass

**bearing** .

```
ResultListener<Location> listener = new ReverseGeocodeListener();
ReverseGeocodeRequest2 request = new ReverseGeocodeRequest2(geoCoord, null, RETRIEVE_ADDRESSES, bearing);
if (request.execute(listener) != ErrorCode.NONE)
{
  // Handle request error ...
}
```

It takes float value and i am confused what should be the value of bearing. i hardcoded some vale which still gives me response and i am getting street name as result/ response of ReverseGeocoding with lat/long/alt, now here comes the problem i want to get the link of Here We Go website of the particular lat/long.

**Case 1:** (What i was trying to do)
 So i Stored a string value of Here We Go url and i wanted to append lat/long to the url i was successful to do so but the link i am getting is showing me just the area not the marker on the lat/long. how can i achieve the marker on that lat/long.

**Case 2:** Is there anything we can do programatically to enter lat/long inside the search textbox of Here We Go(this thing shows marker on the position) and get the url of that search and store it in the string ?

I am also using Place Api for getting nearby place depending on categories, but i am not getting phone number value in response with other values.As i search for it on the developer website it says we need special access but i have Here Premium SDK so can you guys help with this i tried contacting Here but no response.

Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We hope both case 1 & 2 of your question drills down to how to append the search term (in your case lat,long) to the here we go map to get a marker on the map. If this is right, then all you need is to call the here url with the search lat,long like this: https://wego.here.com/search/51.52395,-0.15818

Answer (score 0):

We hope both case 1 & 2 of your question drills down to how to append the search term (in your case lat,long) to the here we go map to get a marker on the map. If this is right, then all you need is to call the here url with the search lat,long like this: wego.here.com/search/51.52395,-0.15818